# UIPopoverPresentationController from a button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I've got a `UITableView` and one cell of it has a `UIButton` in it. This button has an action:

```
    - (IBAction)showPopover:(UIButton *)sender    
{
    ChoseOptionsViewController *contentController = [[ChoseOptionsViewController alloc] init];
    contentController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    UIPopoverPresentationController *copvc = contentController.popoverPresentationController;
    copvc.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    copvc.sourceView = self.view;
    copvc.sourceRect = sender.bounds;
    contentController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
    [self presentViewController:contentController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is that `sender.bounds` returns nothing so the popover is shown in the upper left corner of `self.view`, not by the side of the button.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing your `sourceView` to `sender`:

```
copvc.sourceView = sender;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that I've tried everything, but looks like I missed this one.

Comment: Works Great on iPad